# select2 trigger an element from dropdown via jquery or js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-select2

is there a way to trigger a [select2](https://select2.github.io/) item from the dropdown via jquery or javascript?

I managed to trigger the main select2 element with

```
$("#s2id_address a").trigger({type:'mousedown'});
```

in order to open the Dropdown.

Now i would like to trigger the first Element of the Dropdown, but none of my examples are working;

```
$("#select2-drop ul li[1]").click();
$("#select2-drop ul li[1]").trigger('click');
$("#select2-drop ul li[1]").trigger({type: 'mousedown'});
$("#select2-drop ul li[1]").trigger('change');
```

Comment: If this isn't using AJAX or a custom adapter, you could potentially do this by just setting the `selected` property on the `<option>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a working solution

```
$(".select2-results li:nth-child(LISTINDEX) div").trigger({type:'mouseup'});
```

does the trick